# Branching at the parser lever based on the content of a token

Tags: parsing, ocaml, grammar, ocamllex, menhir

I'm working on a simple example parser/lexer for a tiny project, but I've run into a problem.

I'm parsing content along these lines:

```
Name SEP Gender SEP Birthday
Name SEP Gender SEP Birthday
```

… where `SEP` is any one (but not multiple!) of `|`, `,`, or whitespace.

Now, I didn't want to lock the field-order in at the lexer order, so I'm trying to lex this with a very simple set of tokens:

```
%token <string> SEP
%token <string> VAL
%token NL

%token EOF
```

Now, it's dictated that I produce a parse-error if, for instance, the `gender` field doesn't contain a small set of per-determined values, say `{male,female,neither,unspecified}`. I can *wrap* the parser and deal with this, but I'd really like to encode this requirement into the automaton for future expansion.

My first attempt, looking something like this, failed horribly:

```
doc:
   | EOF              { [] }
   | it = rev_records { it }
   ;

rev_records:
           | (* base-case: empty *) { [] }
           | rest = rev_records; record; NL  { record :: rest }
           | rest = rev_records; record; EOF { record :: rest }
           ;

record:
   last_name = name_field; SEP; first_name = name_field; SEP;
   gender = gender_field; SEP; favourite_colour = colour_field; SEP;
   birthday = date_field
   { {last_name; first_name; gender; favourite_colour; birthday} }

name_field: str = VAL { str }

gender_field:
            | VAL "male" { Person.Male }
            | VAL "female" { Person.Female }
            | VAL "neither" { Person.Neither }
            | VAL "unspecified" { Person.Unspecified }
            ;
```

Yeah, no dice. Obviously, my attempt at an unstructured-lexing is already going poorly.

What's the idiomatic way to parse something like this?

Comment: I'm not an expert at parsers, but I would have tokenized the accepted values since they have syntactic value, and then defined `gender_field` as a union of these tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Parsers, such as Menhir and OCamlYacc, operate on tokens, not on strings or characters. The transformation from characters to tokens is made on the lexer level. That's why you can't specify a string in the production rule.

You can, of course, perform any check in the semantic action and raise an exception, e.g.,

```
record:
   last_name = name_field; SEP; first_name = name_field; SEP;
   gender_val = VAL; SEP; favourite_colour = colour_field; SEP;
   birthday = date_field
   { 
     let gender = match gender_val with
     | "male" -> Person.Male
     | "female" -> Person.Female
     | "neither" -> Person.Neither
     | "unspecified" -> Person.Unspecified
     | _ -> failwith "Parser error: invalid value in the gender field" in
      {last_name; first_name; gender; favourite_colour; birthday}   
    }
```

You can also tokenize possible gender or you can use regular expressions on the lexer level to prevent invalid fields, e.g.,

```
rule token = parser
| "male" | "female" | "neither" | "unspecified" as -> {GENDER s}
...
```

However, this is not recommended, as it will, in fact, turn `male`, `female`, etc into keywords, so their occurrences in other places will break your grammar.

Comment: Maybe you should add the constructors like `Person.Male` that are used in the question.

Comment: Also, handling the gender at lexing time is not that ideal, those words could appear elsewhere and break stuff.

Comment: yep, that's a good point. It basically makes the specified genders keywords. So it shouldn't be a parser error on the first hand.